# Bootstrap 4 horizontal form checkbox not aligning

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate Bootstrap 4 in an Angular 5 app. Rows with checkbox and radio buttons on my horizontal form is not aligning with other rows. I used the code from Bootstrap documentation. This form has sticky navbar and footer. What in my css is causing this problem?

http://plnkr.co/edit/xH6VJo?p=preview

Style:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }
  .footer-text {
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
body {
    min-height: 75rem;
    padding-top: 5rem;
  }
.router-outlet {
    margin: 2rem;
}
```

html inside router-outlet:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Radios</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
              First radio
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
              Second radio
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check disabled">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
              Third disabled radio
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
            Example checkbox
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but fiddling with your plnkr I got it to work by removing `form-check-input`

Comment: The HTML output that you posted here, it actually does align using this code.

Comment: Looks like an inconsistency in 4.x Beta and Alpha.  Your code outputs as expected (correctly aligned) in the 4.0.0 general release.

Comment: @Roberr C Thank you. Updating the reference to general release fixed the problem.

Comment: @RobertC Would you mind converting your comment to an answer? Thx.

Comment: @S.Beliadsi - since the issue is just a bug between the beta/general-release I'd probably recommend just closing/deleting the thread. There isn't really a solution here that will help others as newcomers will most likely be using the public release.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to vertically align the buttons with the labels, set the parent `display` type to `flex` with the `align-items` property set to `center` and remove the top margin of the radio button.

```
.form-check {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.form-check-input {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

If you are trying to fix the sticky footer, set the `position` to `fixed` rather than `absolute`.

```
.footer[_ngcontent-c1] {
    position: fixed;
}
```